# How to check if device in landscape or portrait mode in flat position

Tags: ios, swift

There are some questions about device orientation and some users answered like this:

```
if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
    print("landscape")
} else {
    print("portrait")
}
```

Which is totally wrong because they don't know that it can have the third result: `isFlat`

So it can return three different results:

```
if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
    print("landscape")
} else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat {
    print("flat")
} else { // UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
    print("portrait")
}
```

So if a device is in flat position (`isFlat`) how to check if that device shows content in landscape or portrait mode?

**Update**

Only one of them can be `true`

If `isFlat` returns `true` then both `isLandscape` and `isPortrait` return `false`

**Update 2**

I ended up using:

```
private func isLandscape() -> Bool {
    return self.view.frame.width > self.view.frame.height
}
```

Or we can use `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape`

Comment: switch the orientation

Comment: @LeoDabus what do you mean? Change if...else statement to switch?

Comment: `switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
case .unknown:
    print("The orientation of the device cannot be determined.")
case .portrait:
    print("The device is in portrait mode, with the device held upright and the home button at the bottom.")`

Comment: `case .portraitUpsideDown:print("The device is in portrait mode but upside down, with the device held upright and the home button at the top.")
case .landscapeLeft:print("The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the right side.")
case .landscapeRight:print("The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the left side.")
case .faceUp:print("The device is held parallel to the ground with the screen facing upwards.")`

Comment: `case .faceDown:print("The device is held parallel to the ground with the screen facing downwards.")
}`

Comment: you can check if isFlat or not in any of this cases when needed

Comment: @LeoDabus `.unknown`? How is that possible? With Android SDK I can easily know if a device shows content in landscape or in portrait orientation. I don't care about any flat, face up/down orientations

Comment: `.unknown` is in case of emulator. Anyway you can group them as needed.

Comment: @LeoDabus I just need landscape or portrait, that's all

Comment: Why not check the view's frame? If width < height then it's portrait.

Comment: The `UIDeviceOrientation` enum returned by the `UIDevice.current.orientation` is the physical orientation of the actual device and therefore if the device is physically flat it is not considered landscape or portrait.  It is not related to the orientation of the interface, display, views, etc.  If possible you should avoid thinking in landscape and portrait terms and just have you interface adapt as appropriate (e.g. landscape is just wider than high).

Comment: @rmaddy yes but I thought I could use some built-in iOS SDK functions to make things easier (like in Android)

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth it's just that in Android we can think this way

Comment: Yep but your'e in the iOS world now so that no longer applies.  In iOS Apple strongly discourages you from thinking in terms of landscape and portrait.  Instead think in terms of size classes and make your interface adapt in a more flexible fashion.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth thanks for your comments, now it's clear to me

Comment: @user924 You need to update your question with what you are actually trying to do. Why do you need to know the device orientation? Do you really need to know the device orientation? How you intend to make use of the answer?

Comment: @rmaddy Well you may need it in many cases... I don't know why are asking this... One example is to dynamically change something in UI when rotation changes from portrait to landscape

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth or we can also use `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape` which works in terms of landscape and portrait

Comment: The `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation` is deprecated but does still work at the moment.  I think it was mentioned that it was more deprecated for the setting aspect of it but I still wouldn't rely on it unless absolutely needed.  As for your example of needing to know the orientation to change something in the UI you should try to avoid needing to know landscape or portrait and be more flexible.

Comment: @user924 I'm asking because there is a big difference between needing to know the actual device orientation and knowing the orientation of the view on the screen. Which one do you actually need to know? The answer to that depends on what you plan to do. If you just want to update the view's display, then you do not need to know the device orientation at all. Use the `UIViewController` methods to deal with changes is size and/or traits.

Comment: @rmaddy I needed to find out how my controller shows content (in landscape or in portrait mode). I solved it by using `self.view.frame.width > self.view.frame.height` or `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape`

Comment: Only use the first option. Always base your calculations on the size of the view. The use of `statusBarOrientation` will give you the wrong result in cases such as on an iPad while multitasking. Your app may be tall and skinny while the iPad reports being in landscape.